# Redirecting to a data-toggle tab using the Zend Framework

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework, web-applications

Currently I have a page that has Projects and Families.  The Project index page is the root of the application, so if I go to `/` I will have the list of projects, with a data-toggle tab to the list of families.

I am using the Zend Framework, so when I want to redirect to the list of projects, it's simple:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
```

However, it seems to be much more complicated to redirect to the families tab. Any ideas on how to do this?

My homepage is setup as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#projects"
            data-toggle="tab">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#families" data-toggle="tab">Families</a> </li>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
        <div id="projects" class="tab-pane active"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->active)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('project/project/summary.phtml', $this->active) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="families" class="tab-pane"
            style="margin-bottom: 80px;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <?php echo $family_headers; ?>
                    <?php if (isset($this->families)) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->partialLoop('family/family/summary.phtml', $this->families) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </table>
            </div>  
        </div>      

    </div>
```

I'm guessing there's a way to use the `partialLoop` in the controller, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

In documentation of `toRoute` you can post more than one argument. The third one is `$option`. You can type: `array('fragment' => 'families')` and it will redirect to `you.domain/#families`:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home', array(), array('fragment' => 'families'));
```

I hope it would help you.

Comment: It still seems to be going to the home route, and not the tab.  I think this is partially because `you.domain/#families` still brings up the project summary page

Comment: If i understand you correctly it should be home route. You need force data-toggle to open `#families` tab onLoad

Comment: Yeah, it is on the home route, but I'm not sure how to force it to open the #families tab

Comment: Could you paste your javascript code? Do you have `$( "#tabbable" ).tabs();` onload?